rvm list known doesn't show latest ruby verions
I'm using rvm as the Ruby package manager and was trying to update the ruby version.
rvm list known only shows ruby versions till 3.0.0. I'm using Mac Sonoma (Apple Silicon).
While trying to run rvm install 3.3.5, I get an error that arch arm64 is not found. Is the highest supported ruby version for Apple Silicon 3.0.0?

The PR adding the newest Ruby version to RVM wasn’t merged yet: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/pull/5499

If 3.0.0 is the latest version you get: any chance you're on the stable branch instead of master? They don't seem to keep the (so-called) stable branch up-to-date (last update 4 years ago). If so, try rvm get master

rbenv and rvm generally require definitions be included in the version manager. If you need to build an undefined version, consider using ruby-install (from the same author as chruby) to install any arbitrary version into your Ruby version manager of choice. That approach works with (almost) any published Ruby version that's not EOL, and in my own experience it certainly works with rbenv and others, although I haven't tested it specifically with rvm.
